# sine, cosine and the exponential by their differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was thinking about some elementary uniqueness facts concerning the definition of the exponential function and the trigonometric functions by their differential equations.

> Show that any pair of functions functions $f, g ∈ C^1(ℝ)$ satisfying $f' = g$ and $g' = -f$ is uniquely determined by $f(0)$ and $g(0)$.

Do not use the exponential function or any trigonometric function in doing so, but only use the definition of derivatives and the common rules for differentiating. You don’t have to prove existence, but only uniqueness.
Also, I was wondering about this one:

> Show that there is at most one function $f ∈ C^1(ℝ)$ such that $f = f'$ and $f(0) = 1$.

I know you can easily do this by noting that the exponential function doesn’t vanish, while satisfying the equation, and then looking at $\frac{f}{\exp}$. But can you derive that such an $f$ doesn’t vanish either to do the same trick without using the exponential function explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(f_1,g_1)$ and $(f_2,g_2)$ are solutions of the system $f'=g, g'=-f$ and $c\in\mathbb R$, then so are $(f_1+f_2,g_1+g_2)$ and $(cf_1,cg_1)$, i.e. the solutions form a vector space $V$.
The map $\phi\colon V\to\mathbb R^2$, $(f,g)\mapsto (f(0),g(0))$ is linear.
Let $h(x)=f^2(x)+g^2(x)$. Then $h'=2ff'+2gg'=2fg-2gf=0$, so $h$ is constant.
Especially, if $\phi(f,g)=(0,0)$, then $h(x)=0$ for all $x$ and hence $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x$, i.e. $\phi$ is injective as was to be shown.

---

Assume $f'=f$ and $f(a)=0$ for some $a$.
Choose $r>0$. Then the continuous function $f$ is bounded on $[a-1,a+1]$, say $|f(x)|<M$ for $a-1\le x\le a+1$. This is the case $n=0$ of the statement
$$\tag1 |f(a+h)|\le M|h|^n \qquad\text{for }|h|<1.$$
Assume $(1)$ holds for some $n\in\mathbb N_0$. Then 
$$ f(a+h)=f(a+h)-f(a)=h\cdot f'(a+\theta h)\qquad\text{for some }\theta\in[0,1].$$
Hence for $h$ with $|h|<1$ we have
$$|f(a+h)|=|h|\cdot |f'(a+\theta h)|=|h|\cdot |f(a+\theta h)|\le |h|\cdot M(|\theta h|)^n\le M|h|^{n+1}$$
and $(1)$ follows by induction for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$.
Letting $n\to\infty$, we conclude $f(a+h)=0$ for all $|h|<1$.
We conclude that $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $f'=f$ and $f(0)=0$ must be identically zero.
If $f_1,f_2$ are two solutions of $f=f'$ then so is $f_1-f_2$. Especially, if $f_1(0)=f_2(0)$, then $f_1-f_2$ is identically zero, i.e. $f_1=f_2$ as was to be shown.

Comment: That’s plausible! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, suppose we have two such functions $f$ and $g$. Let $h = f - g$. Then $h' = h$ and $h(0) = 0$. We show by induction that $h$ is zero on $[0, n/2]$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. The proof for $n < 0$ is similar.

So suppose $h(n/2) = 0$, from the inductive hypothesis, and let $x$ be a point in $[n/2,(n+1)/2]$ where |h| attains its maximum in that interval. Integrating both sides of $h = h'$ gives $\int_{n/2}^x h(t)dt = h(x)-h(n/2) = h(x)$. But we also have $|\int_{n/2}^xf(t)dt| \le (x-n/2)|h(x)| \le |h(x)/2|$. So $|h(x)| \le |h(x)/2|$, which is only possible if $h(x) = 0$.